# adding a start up via command line (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, startup

Hey, I'm trying to have a graphical program and I want it to start after I log in. How do I do so? I know there's a GUI program, but I want to use a command line here.

GUI tool:
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/07/ubuntu-open-applications-automatically-during-system-startup/

now, there is update-rc.d, however, it seems to run **before** I log in, while the entire system loads ups (Unless I don't understand what the *NN* means in the update-rc.d manual).
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

There's also an autostart folder in ~/.config/autostart - which is profile (or user) specific. If you put a .desktop file in /etc/xdg/autostart it will become a global startup for any new users created. This assumes you have xdg-user-dirs-gtk installed.

Answer (score 2):

Drop a [.desktop file](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/) in... `/etc/xdg/autostart` here, might be different on Ubuntu.

Comment: Can we do this remotely ?

Comment: If you can get access to the filesystem, of course you can.